# flexUnitTasks error of "command not understood"

Tags: ant, flexunit

I use FlexUnitTasks-4.0.0.jar to generate report with ant, and the compile target is passed,  and the testRunner swf file is made, but  has some problem, the log is following:

```
 [flexunit] Receiving data ...
 [flexunit] Sending acknowledgement to player to start sending test data ...
 [flexunit] 
 [flexunit] Stopping server ...
 [flexunit] End of test data reached, sending acknowledgement to player ...
 [flexunit] Closing client connection ...
 [flexunit] Closing server on port [1024] ...
java.concurrent.Exception:command [<testcase classname="" ...>] not understood
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out ant task version corresponds to flexunit version (e.i. use anttask-4.0 with FU-4.0).
It's better to download everything from site http://www.flexunit.org/?page_id=14.